# Why can't I import PyTorch? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inf'

Tags: pytorch

I have a code using PyTorch, but got the following error in the first line when I tried to import PyTorch. I am using Python3.4 and PyTorch-0.4

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/my_path/lib/python3.4/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ._six import string_classes as _string_classes
  File "/my_path/lib/python3.4/site-packages/torch/_six.py", line 33, in <module>
    inf = math.inf
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inf'
```

Any idea why I got this error? Thanks!

Comment: It says [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) that `math.inf` is new in Python3.5.

Comment: Make sure your python versions are `Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.* `